# viewing queue/service bus messages from multiple clients

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azureservicebus

I am learning how to communicate between Azure cloud apps and client apps, and worked through [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/compute-intensive-task-on-a-virtual-machine/) tutorial.

I currently have a single instance of a .exe worker process which sends messages via the service bus.  I also have a client role which I run on my local machine to read the messages.  However, when I run multiple instances of the client, each client picks up some of the messages and none of them is getting a full readout.  Is it possible to use a queue or the service bus so that **every** instance of the client can see **all** of the messages  generated by the worker?

For example, 3 people on 3 different computers might want to independently monitor the status of the same compute task.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In that case you shouldn't be working with Service Bus Queues but with Service Bus Topics/Subscriptions.

> In contrast to Service Bus queues, where each message is processed by
>   a single consumer, topics and subscriptions provide a one-to-many form
>   of communication, using a publish/subscribe pattern. It is possible to
>   register multiple subscriptions to a topic. When a message is sent to
>   a topic, it is then made available to each subscription to
>   handle/process independently.

For your example you would need 1 Service Bus Topic with a Subscription on that Topic for **each client application**.

More information: [How to Use Service Bus Topics/Subscriptions](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/)

Comment: Thanks for the information. 

Does this mean the subscription should be added before sending the message on that topic in order to receive using that subscription?

Answer (score -1):

Because I believe you are using "Peek" as a message receive mode which will share (not equally) total messages between the instances you run.

Hope that helps.